# How to wait for thread to complete without blocking UI

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, threadpool

I want my program to wait after below line

```
frmProgressBarObj = PullMSI.ExtractByMSIName("products.txt", false);
```

as above method is internally calling thread through StartProcessWithProgress() method . I want that thread to be completed before //code logic -2 line gets executed. At the same time, It should not stop UI update done by frmProgressBar.UpdateProgress(). How do I do this?

```
namespace NS1
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {                
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmProgressBar frmProgressBarObj = PullMSI.ExtractByMSIName("products.txt", false);
            //code logic - 2
            MessageBox.Show("This is executing immediately. 
                             I want to wait until above thread is complete");
        }
    }

    public partial class frmProgressBar : Form
    {

        public void UpdateProgress(String strTextToDisplayOnProgress)
        {
            progressBar1.BeginInvoke(
                   new Action(() => 
                   { 
                       progressBar1.Value++; 
                       lblFileName.Text = strTextToDisplayOnProgress;
                       if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
                       {
                           this.Hide(); 
                        } 
                    }));
        }

        public delegate void DelProgress();

        public void StartProcessWithProgress(DelProgress delMethodCode, int maxCount)
        {
            InitializeProgress(maxCount);
            Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delMethodCode));
            backgroundThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static class PullMSI
    {
        public static frmProgressBar ExtractByMSIName(String strProductFilePath, bool reNameMSI)
        {
            frmProgressBar frmProgressBar = new frmProgressBar();

            frmProgressBar.StartProcessWithProgress(() =>
            {
                //StreamRader sr declaration and other code

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //logic here
                    frmProgressBar.UpdateProgress("Copying sr.msiname");
                }
            }, 2);

            return frmProgressBar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UI? This is a console application.

Comment: My bad. Sorry, In order to simplify code, I just put all classes in console application so that I can easily post here. But its Windows form application and process start on button click.

Comment: You can use either of these: 1) TPL with task continuation 2) Reset events (ManualResetEventSlim/AutoResetEventSlim) 3) Using other mechanism such as Semaphore (highly discourage your from doing this) 4) async/await if you're running .Net 4.5+. 5) Producer/Consumer (overkill for your use-case). Basically there are a variety of ways this is possible. Do a read up on these and pick one that you like most.

Comment: Actually I have not used these techniques before and it will take time for me to learn. Client expectation is haunting me :( any code sample will be great help.

Comment: You must not wait in a UI event-handler - it's a state-machine and must service its input queue promptly.  Bocking waits with events/semaphores are not useable at all.  Message signalling systems like Invoke/BeginInvoke are saner.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Below are three different ways you can achieve what you want:

**1. Using reset events** ([further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim)). If your C# version doesn't have the `ManualResetEventSlim`, replace it with `ManualResetEvent` and change `Wait()` with `WaitOne()`

```
class LockingWithResetEvents
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void Test()
    {
        MethodUsingResetEvents();
    }

    private void MethodUsingResetEvents()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => DoSomethingLong());
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => ShowMessageBox());
    }

    private void DoSomethingLong()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something.");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        _resetEvent.Set();
    }

    private void ShowMessageBox()
    {
        _resetEvent.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world.");
    }
}
```

**2) Using Task Parallel Library (TPL).** ([Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl))

```
class LockingWithTPL
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(DoSomethingLong).ContinueWith(result => ShowMessageBox());
    }

    private void DoSomethingLong()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something.");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    private void ShowMessageBox()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world.");
    }
}
```

**3) Using Async/Await.** ([Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh191443(v=vs.140)))

```
class LockingWithAwait
{
    public void Test()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    private async void DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => DoSomethingLong());
        ShowMessageBox();
    }

    private async void DoSomethingLong()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something.");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    private void ShowMessageBox()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world.");
    }
}
```

Also good to know: [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex), [`Semaphore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore), [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement), [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim), [`Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor) and [`Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked).

Comment: Doesn't your `Test` method need to be declared `Async` also?  I thought that all methods that call Async methods had to also be Async.  Async/Await is still a little new to me, so I may have that wrong.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Doesn't have to. I'm not `await`ing anything. If you're not awaiting it, it doesn't need the `async` keyword and will instead treat it as a simple method with void return type. This however would not compile: `await DoSomething();`.

Comment: NO, no, no waiting in UI event-handlers!

Comment: @MartinJames Was that meant for me? none of the three solutions I have posted will block the calling thread I believe.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 4.0 (with VS2012) or above, you can do this quite easily with the [`Task Parallel Library`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`async-await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmProgressBar frmProgressBarObj = await Task.Run(() =>
                      PullMSI.ExtractByMSIName("products.txt", false));

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Returned {0}", frmProgressBarObj.ToString());
}
```

For .NET 4, you'll need to add [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).

Comment: It's worth noting that this is an option only if the author is working with .NET 4.5

Comment: @TomC. .NET 4.0 also supports `async-await` with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov For some values of "support"

Comment: It's not native and requires a lot of hacking and tweaking for .NET 4. Not the approach you want, especially for more complex use-cases